# Load page content of link in div when clicked

Tags: css, anchor, html

Hoping someone could assist me with this issue,

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnL1d663/3/) with the code

I have created some basic code of a site with a header, navigation menu with six links, the main div and right side sidebar,

What I am looking to achieve is that when a user clicks one of the six page links on the nav menu (e.g clicks `page4.html`).

The content from that page link which was clicked (e.g `page4.html`), is loaded into the main div without the rest of the page (i.e header, nav, right sidebar), refreshing at all.

That div should remain to show that content (e.g `page4.html`) until the user clicks another link (e.g `page6.html`).

Then only the content in the main div should change from (e.g `page4.html` to `page 6.html`) without any other content reloading/refreshing of the page

Hopefully, I have been able to make it clear enough of what I'm need to do.

---

Here is the code:

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
}

.nav {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 500px;
  background: grey;
}

.main {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  height: 500px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.rightsidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 500px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">Site name</div>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page1.html</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page2.html</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page3.html</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page4.html</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page5.html</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page6.html</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">This is the Main Div that will load either page1.html -> page6.html depending on which Nav link the user clicks.. Note that when user clicks the nav link.. Only this div should reload with the content of said clicked page. i.e. If user clicks page4.html
      link in nva menu. This lightblue div will change from whats written here now and load the content from page4.html in this div but the header, Nav, and rightsidebar of the page will stay static and not refresh at all.</div>
    <div class="rightsidebar">blah blah blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: why use div instead of iframe?

Comment: i try stay away from them ideally. But i could use an iframe if needed as long as when the link is clicked only the iframe loaded in the div and page doesnt refresh

Comment: That you describe can be done with ajax call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use jQuery's load function. Give your navigation anchors unique ID's, and from there you can use some code similar to this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#nav_page_a").on("click", function () {
        $("#main").load("PageA.html");
    });
    $("#nav_page_b").on("click", function () {
        $("#main").load("PageB.html");
    });
});
```

Have a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: How will this affect search engine results? as if a user searches for something on page 3, i would like the whole page displayed and not just the content on page 3?

Comment: To be honest I've never built a website using a convention like this, and I'm actually curious as to why you're not instead using server side includes (or a masterpage if .NET) for the header/nav/footer and simply creating individual pages for each "page".

Comment: Also @Shikhar's answer below is the way to go, mine was a long-winded way to get it working AND to get you to see how it worked, his is succinct, and scaleable. It deserves to be the best answer, actually.

Comment: Thank you, I did try his answer, but was unable to get it to work somehow, where yours did. Well basically i want the site to behave like it normally would in regards to urls for each page and SEO etc. But just want that nav, header, footer etc. stay static and only the main div refreshes and not the whole page.  Im sure a server side option would rob be ideal but i have no idea where to start or what language or software would be needed.

Comment: I see, fair enough, well are you using PHP, Java, ASP.NET? Or perhaps a better question might be is your hosting service for the website Windows or Linux?

Comment: I used the sample code when trying his js. but more likely a mistake my side. I am Using a linux server, and my webpage is created with php and html coding, some js,css and a mysql db. But someone mentioned for me to look at pjax or spf js to implement what im needing. which seems the best option

Comment: Thank you, I'll Give it a try when i get a chance later and give some feedback. I may not need the code anymore but may still be useful for others.

Answer (score 11):

Add href attributes to your links to the respective pages you want to go to.

```
<li><a href="Page1.html">Page1.html</a></li>
<li><a href="Page2.html">Page2.html</a></li>
```

And then the following should solve your issue via **Jquery**

```
$(function(){
    $(".nav li a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //To prevent the default anchor tag behaviour
        var url = this.href;
        $(".main").load(url);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

using jQuery

```
$(".main").load("yourpage.html");
```